# "App not found" for only applications in folders and on SD card

Tags: samsung, sd-card, system-error, 8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I rebooted my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge this morning, however, upon restart any applications that are on the SD card and in a folder get the message "App Not Found" when trying to launch. These apps also have the grey SD card icon.

Moving the app out into the root tray allows the application to launch. However, moving the app to internal storage doesn't.

Uninstalling and reinstalling an app doesn't help. Neither does clearing system cache.

Is there a fix for this? The workaround is to move all apps out of folders, but this means I can't organise them as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution appeared to be :

- settings
- apps
- show system apps on menu
- Samsung experience home
- clear cache
- force stop

Answer (score 1):

I did this. It didn't work. I then set about moving the apps I'd moved back to the internal memory starting with iPlayer. As soon as I had moved iPlayer the icons for the other apps I'd moved to the SD card regained their colour (they'd previously been greyed out) and started working...

This was on Galaxy Tab Active.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try Restart.
2) Unmount sd card, then clicked on mount sd card.
3) Try Another Launcher